# How to insert/edit hierarchyid field as text in SQL studio

Tags: sql-server

In SQL server 2008 I have a hierarchical field (hierarchyid). How do I change its value or insert new row when using SQL Server Management Studio "edit rows" command? Is there a textual representation that will be converted to an ID?

Yes, I know I could do it using a query, but I would like to *manually* enter it as *TEXT* using the studio editor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can convert a HIERARCHYID to a string using:

```
hierarchyField.ToString();
```

You'll get something like '/1/', '/1/1/', '/1/2/' and so forth.

And you can convert such a string representation back to a HIERARCHYID with

```
SET hierarchyField = hierarchyid::Parse(string)
```

or

```
CAST('/2/' AS hierarchyid)
```

More details on this can be found on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx)

Comment: yes, but how can you enter that number in the textual table editor in the studio? The only special character that i know is NULL - it automatically gets converted from text to NULL value.

Comment: I don't think you can enter those values in the interactive table editor - you'll need to use a SQL script to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can enter the hierarchyID directly into the Visual Studio table as strings.

1.) For the root ID you just type a forward slash:  /

2.) For one level down: /1/  (must include the trailing slash)

3.) For another leaf, same level as step 2 above: /2/

4.) For the child of /1/: /1/1/

5.) Second child of /1/: /1/2/

etc. Hope this helps.